# how to get content from different servers using richfaces/jsf?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

To speed up our website (that contains MANY images), we would like to deliver content from different subdomains, e.g.
server1.example.com
server2.example.com
server3.example.com
server4.example.com
server5.example.com
server6.example.com

these will all point to the same IP, but will get around the max 2 connections to same domain issue (that the clients browser has) and load more images in paralllel.

Our content is however generated by the a4j:mediaOutput tag which generates a relative url.

is there any way to tell the a4j:mediaOutput tag to add a specific domain in front of the relative url?

Or an alternative way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about setting up a proxy?  A proxy server has the single IP address and domain and is public facing, and then if configured for load balancing can forward requests and responses as a middle man between client and ACTUAL server (which the client can't access directly, it sits behind the firewall).

For JSF applications I typically set up 2 or more Apache web servers behind a proxy and serve static web content from these web servers (Eg. javascripts, stylesheets, images and static HTML).

I then use `mod_jk` of Apache to forward dynamic content requests to load balanced application servers (JBoss works).

Comment: no, i only want to have different servernames to trick the browser to create more than 2 connections to the same server, hence making the page content load faster.